# Listar grupo apenas que contenham itens

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

E um exemplo de `model`:

```
public class Grupo
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Nome {get;set;}

   public ICollection<Item> Itens {get;set:}
}
```

E os itens

```
public class Item
{
  publit int Id {get;set;}
  public int GrupoId {get;set;}
  public string Nome {get;set;}
}
```

Existe alguma forma de eu filtrar via `EF` apenas os grupos que contenham Itens ?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente tens de dar referencia na `class Item` para a `Grupo`:

```
public class Item
{
  publit int Id {get;set;}
  public int GrupoId {get;set;}
  public string Nome {get;set;}
  public virtual Grupo Grupo { get; set; } // <-

}
```

Depois basta fazer uma consulta em `Grupo` para verificar se tem `Item`:

```
var listaGrupos = db.Grupo.Where(a => a.Itens.Count > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: Como Itens é uma ICollection<Item>, acredito que não tenha a propriedade `Count` e o Método `Count` pode ter um custo muito acima do aceitavel nesta situação.

Uma Opção seria o Método `Any`, porem ao meu ver este ainda um custo elevado, a melhor solução ao meu ver seria um Contains, isto se ele estiver a usar EF5 ou superior.

Comment: @TobyMosque, como disseste e bem, tanto o Contains ou o Any dá. Agora a nível de melhor solução já não consigo ter um bom feedback

Answer (score 1):

Caso esteja a usar EF5 ou superior, acredito que a melhor solução envolva um `Contains`.

```
var gruposID = db.Itens.Select(item => item.GrupoId).Distinct().ToList();
var listaGrupos = db.Grupos.Where(grupo => gruposID.Contains(grupo.GrupoId));
```